# SoundCloud api call keeps showing as "object is not a function" inside nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, soundcloud, typeerror

I'm just starting out with soundcloud api so I copied their example in order to do some basic tests. However, some simple tasks don't seem to work. The code below is the basic example I used to learn how to search, yet nodejs says object is not a function.

```
SC.get('/tracks', { q: 'buskers', license: 'cc-by-sa' }, function (tracks) {
    console.log(tracks);
});
```

Also, when it comes to parameters I get a lot of "undefined" errors...Not in this one, but others...Any advice or solutions? Thanks for your time and consideration. :)

Ok... (you guys asked for more details) This is my require and inti setup. I might run a debug report (because that was mentioned as well), but I'm not sure how to do so...

```
var SC = require('node-soundcloud');

// Initialize client with additional accessToken field
SC.init({
    id: '***',
    secret: '***',
    uri: 'https://soundcloud.com/connect',
    accessToken: 'https://api.soundcloud.com/oauth2/token'
});
```

Any more ideas on a solution?

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the javascript library. Did you consider opening a bug report?

Comment: Show more source... where is your `require` and `init` ?

Comment: I added both require and init, however i'm not sure how to do open up a bug report just yet.

Comment: I already changed the numbers and letters around, its not real  :)